# Div not stacked on top of other elements

Tags: css

I am having some issues getting an image that is the background of the ftrBottomBanner div to be on top of the black and green areas on my page.  I have tried the z-index of the div at 999, and also adding the overflow property to the parent divs with no luck.  I know it is something simple, but can not find what I am missing.

The image below is what I am trying to achieve.  Positioning the orange banner inside of a div  over top of the black and overlapping the black and green area.

sample image: http://www.woodsequipment.com/uploadedimages/layering_question.png

The Black and Green bands are individual divs positioned relative and there is a container div centered on the black area that will contain a menu and then the orange banner.

What I am trying to do is have the orange banner overlap into the green area.

Here is the CSS:

```
/**** Footer ****/
div#footer{position:relative; width:100%; bottom:0; border:1px solid blue;}
    div#footerBlackRibbon{position:relative; height:51px; width:100%; background-color:#000000;border:1px solid white;}
    div#bottomMenuContainer{position: relative; top: 0px; left:0px; height:50px; width: 950px; margin: 0 auto; border:1px solid red; }
        div#ftrBottomBanner{position:absolute; top:0px; left:695px; background-image: url(images/footerBanner.png); width:216px; height:137px; background-repeat:no-repeat; border:3px solid aqua; z-index:999;}
        div#ftrBlackMenu{position:relative; top:18px; left:0px; }

div#footerGreenRibbon{position:relative; height:187px; width:100%; background-color:#bed73d; overflow:visible;}

div#footerWhiteRibbon{position:relative; height:30px; width:100%; background-color:#ffffff; }
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footerBlackRibbon">                     
        <div id="bottomMenuContainer">
            <div id="ftrBottomBanner"></div> 
                <div id="ftrBlackMenu">                        
                    <ul id="navlist">
                        <li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Dealer Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Woods</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms of use</a></li>
                    </ul>                        
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footerGreenRibbon">
        </div>
        <div id="footerWhiteRibbon">
        </div>  
    </div>
```

I hope this is a bit clearer.

Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tshirts/kAV42/1/

It appears to be working there, but not on my page with the same code in any browser.

Comment: Hi tshirts. Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ with working images and clean css? It's very difficult to see the problem otherwise.

Comment: I edited the original question with a link on what I am trying to achieve.  My problem is the Green ribbon is showing over the banner with is set with absolute positioning and a z-index of 999.

Comment: If it works on jsFiddle, but not at your site, probably you have some other styles which overwrites styles which you gave us. If you still need help there is no other way then showing a link to your site. It's hard to make working what is working :)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate you looking. The weird part is I created a page with the same exact code I out on jsFiddle and it still didn't work on my development site.  Right now it is just on my local machine so I have no URL to it.  We are in process of a site redesign so it is just initial development.  Thanks though.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot, it is an IE9 issue only.  Everything is working fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari for PC.  Our new parent company upgraded my whole machine over night and I didn't realize they did, so IE went from 8 to 9 without me noticing.